# Offline image showing Twitch WP Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, twitch

I am writing a Twitch Wordpress status plugin that shows a simple image if its online or offline, however I am unable to get it to work. Below is the file

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Twitch Status - InvidiousAus
Description: Displays an image if the Twitch channel "invidiousaus" is online.
Author: Your Name
Version: 1.0
*/

function smfr_twitch_get_stream_status($channel) {
    $client_id = 'we57gvgtlmhqnmk44d3mcbc68rgrd1'; // Replace with your Twitch API Client ID

    $api_url = "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_login={$channel}";
    $headers = array(
        'Client-ID' => $client_id,
    );

    $args = array(
        'headers' => $headers,
    );

    $response = wp_remote_get($api_url, $args);

    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        return "Error fetching Twitch status.";
    }

    $response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response);

    if ($response_code === 200) {
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
        $data = json_decode($body, true);
        if (!empty($data['data'])) {
            return 'online';
        }
    }

    return 'offline';
}

function smfr_twitch_status_fnc() {
    $channel = 'invidiousaus'; // Update to "invidiousaus"

    $stream_status = smfr_twitch_get_stream_status($channel);

    if ($stream_status === 'online') {
        // If the channel is live, show the "online" image
        $html = "<div class='smfr-twitch-status'><img src='" . plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "img/en_ligne.jpg'></div>";
    } else {
        // If the channel is offline, show the "offline" image
        $html = "<div class='smfr-twitch-status'><img src='" . plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "img/hors_ligne.jpg'></div>";
    }

    return $html;
}

function smfr_twitch_status_style() {
    // Register the stylesheet for the plugin (if needed)
    // wp_enqueue_style('smfr_twitch_status_style', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'style.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'smfr_twitch_status_style');

add_shortcode('smfr_twitch_status', 'smfr_twitch_status_fnc');
```

Attempted to Try different API end points with Null result

The expectation is to show online for channels on twitch.tv that are online

Comment: Note key details were edited but are examples only

Comment: So what have you done so far to try and debug this? Have you at least checked what actual response you got?

Comment: The response I got from Twitch API was forbidden

Answer (score 0):

Your `$headers` are missing `Authorization: Bearer 2gbdx6oar67tqtcmt49t3wpcgycthx` or similar token.

From https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference/#get-streams,
Authorization Requires an  [app access token](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/#app-access-tokens) or [user access token](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication#user-access-tokens).

Read the docs to see how to acquire such a token. This is probably oAuth flow. Basically you create an app then you got client_id and client_secret. Using the client_secret you request the token. Once you get it, you can use add it to the header, then use the API on behalf of your app. (User access token might be different flow).